# Hosting a VPN on Heroku

Tags: heroku, vpn

I was wondering if it's possible to host a private vpn on heroku?

My (hypothetical) use case is that let's say there's some service that's only available in Europe but I want to access it in the USA. I'd like to turn a European heroku server into a personal vpn that just allows me to access that service.

I did some research and can't find anyone else who's tried/documented this.

Comment: Any server with ssh access can be used, checkout the following tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: This guide `a non-root user with sudo privileges` which is not possible on heroku

Answer (score 0):

You basically want a proxy. So heroku forbids running an open proxy, so you should restrict use.

> XIX. Operate an “open proxy” or any other form of Internet proxy service that is capable of forwarding requests to any end user or third-party-supplied Internet host;
> --https://www.heroku.com/policy/aup

But technically it is possible - you might want to try it: https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere, if you want to use the browser you will need to download the headers from the [server.js](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/blob/master/server.js) file

Note that this project is not intended to be used as an open proxy, so for example [relative paths are not loaded properly](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/issues/61).

---

You might want to try it - it might be more appropriate, I just did not try it myself ... :)
https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy#setup-a-basic-stand-alone-proxy-server

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31608589)

Comment: What should I do in this case? Copy all the repo source code here?!